# Understanding the §11.2-4 from N3690 draft

Tags: c++

In C++ N3690 draft.

> A base class B of N is accessible at R, if
>
> - an invented public member of B would be a public member of N, or
> - **R occurs in a member or friend of class N**, and an invented public member of B would be a private or protected member of N, or
> - R occurs in a member or friend of a class P derived from N, and an invented public member of B would be a private or protected member of
>     P, or
> - there exists a class S such that B is a base class of S accessible at R and S is a base class of N accessible at R.

Can someone provide me a code for the above statement ?

I tried doing like this.

```
class B {
public:
    int m;
};

class S: private B {
    N r;
};

class N: private S {
    void f() {
        B* p = this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `N` is not a member or friend of class `S`. Your `r` is, but it *isn't* `N`, it merely has type `N`.

To make it a member:

```
struct B {
    int m;
};

struct S : private B {
    struct N;
};

struct S::N : private S {
    void f() {
        B* p = this;
    }
};
```

To make it a friend:

```
struct B {
    int m;
};

struct S : private B {
    friend struct N;
};

struct N : private S {
    void f() {
        B* p = this;
    }
};
```